# Set local variable on DevOps Build Pipeline and use the variable in "Build number format"

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops

I want to have current week number in the build number.
I have defined the variable called currentWeekin the Build Pipeline
In pipeline I have a Powershell task where I do the following:
`$curWeek = Get-Date -UFormat %V Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentWeek;]$curWeek"`
When I enable system.debug = true and run the pipeline I can see the correct value is assigned to $curWeek by "Get-Date -UFormat %V" expression.
On Option tab of pipeline in the Build Number Format field I have added expression as follows: $(Date:yy).$(currentWeek).$(Rev:r)
The middle part $(currentWeek) stays empty.

How should I achieve it?
THanks

Tried `$curWeek = Get-Date -UFormat %V Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentWeek;]$curWeek"`
and `$(Date:yy).$(currentWeek).$(Rev:r)` in Build number format

Was expecting the result to be 23.37.1, but the result is 23..1 which means the currentWeek stays empty